# SAPUI5 MultiCombo tokens aren't displaying correctly

Tags: sapui5

I have a multiCombo box:

-its items are bound to my /Roles entity

-its selectedItems (tokens) are bound to the User/Roles enitity.

Items are fine.

In the controller I've bound User/Roles (the selected items/tokens) using the change event, because otherwise a call is not made to the backend without a refresh.

```
view.bindElement({
                        path: `/Registrations('${registrationId}')`,
                        parameters: {
                            expand: "User/Roles"
                        },
                        events: {
                            change: (event) => {
                                const contextBinding = event.getSource();
                                contextBinding.refresh(true);
                            },  
                            dataRequested: () => {
                                view.setBusy(true);
                            },
                            dataReceived: data => {
                                view.setBusy(false);
```

...

This all works, apart from the selecteditem(tokens) no longer display correctly

See example below where the tokens should be Payer & Budget Manager, not just Payer.

[image]

A browser refresh solves the issue but that is not an acceptable solution.